# How can I inspect internals of Spring4D IDictionary - content of TDictionary?

Tags: dictionary, delphi, spring4d

```
var
dictIntf : IDictionary;

begin
...
dictIntf := TCollections.CreateDictionary<Integer,Integer>;
dictIntf.Add(1,2);
...
end;
```

I tried Debug/Inspect/Type Cast and insert Spring.Collections.Dictionaries.TDictionary<System.Integer,System.Integer>, but a message pops up: ...expression error.

Comment: This is a question I've always wondered about, though I use Ilists the most.